# Undefined reference for external library (C++, QT, Ubuntu 14, CCV)

Tags: c++, qt, g++, computer-vision, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run the CCV library linked at http://libccv.org/ in QT Creator on Ubuntu 14. I followed this tutorial http://libccv.org/tutorial/ and I'm trying now to run the first simple example. I get these errors:

- error: undefined reference to ccv_read_impl(void const*, ccv_dense_matrix_t**, int, int, int, int)
- error: undefined reference to ccv_write(ccv_dense_matrix_t*, char*, int*, int, void*)

This  is the .pro file of the project:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../CNN/ccv/lib/ -lccv

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../CNN/ccv/lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../CNN/ccv/lib

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../CNN/ccv/lib/libccv.a
```

Finally this is the command generated by QT in the compile output:

- g++ -m64 -o ccv1 main.o   -L/home/fabri/QT/CCV1/ccv1/../../../CNN/ccv/lib/ -lccv

I suppose it's a compiler problem but I don't know what. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if I get it right, you  -L/home/fabri/QT/CCV1/ccv1/../../../CNN/ccv/lib/ is equivalent to  -L/home/fabri/CNN/ccv/lib/. Do you have such directory? Is there libccv.a here? Or maybe libccv.so?

Comment: It's a linker error (linker != compiler). Instead of `-L$$PWD/../../../CNN/ccv/lib/` use the full path to that directory. Make sure you have **libccv.so** in there.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Yes I have that directory, the library is libccv.a

Comment: @karlphillip I wrote `LIBS += -L/home/fabri/CNN/ccv/lib -lccv` and it still gives the same error. The library is .a, not .so

Answer (score 2):

Modify the example and try to include it like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "ccv.h"
}
```